# Fieldset legend CSS rendering behavior has changed in recent months... what happened?

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I have a form with various nested `<fieldset>` elements, each with a `<legend>`, and today I noticed an error in my web page on all the browsers I've checked (Chrome, Firefox, Opera) which was not present earlier (6-12 months ago).

There is a `<span class="undo">` element which displays as a curly green arrow using a `background-image`. The intent is for it to get displayed when the surrounding `<fieldset>` has `class="modified"` and hidden otherwise --- this is implemented by changing the `width` of the span.

The old behavior (still shows up on my Chromebook running Chrome OS 76.0.3809.136) which renders consistently with my intent:

[image]

The new behavior (on Chrome 87.0.4280.88 on my Windows 10 PC) has the "Foo configurator" wrapping to two lines for some reason.

[image]

Did something change in browser rendering recently to cause this? If so, what, and how can I fix?

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><style type="text/css">
  form {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
  body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  fieldset {
    padding: 0;
  }
  fieldset > legend {
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
  }  
  span.undo {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
    display: inline-block;
    height: 13px;
    width: 1em;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
  }
  legend > span.undo {
    width: 0em;
  }
  fieldset.modified > legend > span.undo {
    width: 1em;
  }
  div.description {
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-size: 90%;
  }
</style></head>
<body>
<form>
  <fieldset class="field">
    <legend title="">Foo configurator<span class="undo" title="Restore default"></span></legend>
    <label title="">
    <input name="foo_type" type="radio" value="123">Foo #1</label> <div class="description">First foo</div>
    <span class="field-content">
      <label><input name="foo_enable" type="checkbox" value="value">Enable</label>
      <span class="undo" title="Restore default"></span>
      <div class="description">Zoppity</div>
  </span>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field modified">
    <legend title="">Bar configurator<span class="undo" title="Restore default"></span></legend>
    <label title="">
    <input name="bar_type" type="radio" value="123">Bar #1</label> <div class="description">First bar</div>
    <span class="field-content">
      <label><input name="bar_enable" type="checkbox" value="value">Enable</label>
      <span class="undo" title="Restore default"></span>
      <div class="description">Zoppity</div>
  </span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't edit my HTML; the code I have could be saved as a single file and tried out on a PC. Splitting it up into CSS and HTML fragments in SO-form negates that advantage.

Comment: Happens to me on FireFox too! I don't understand the large bounty, what are you hoping for Jason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can see it correctly on Chrome 76, it's likely this change has been introduced by turning on [LayoutNG](https://www.chromium.org/blink/layoutng/#:%7E:text=LayoutNG%20is%20a%20new%20layout,issues%20around%20floats%20and%20margins.) in Chrome 77, which has been released in 2019 already, but some parts of it came out later. For example, I know I had some inconsistency with layouting in textareas and had to have a hack until about last year.

It would be ideal to test with Chrome 77 to see if it really is this thing or not.

Anyway, this looks like an interplay between the `margin-right: -2px` and `width: 0em` that it somehow calculates the layout as overflowing and add a new line.

By using BrowserStack I found it changed in Chrome 86 which happens to be a version in which Chrome implemented [flex and grid for fieldsets](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5962796351094784). They may have needed subtle changes for this to happen as well.

Answer (score 3):

The negative margin is pulling `legend`'s right border to left by 2px thus reduces legend's width by 2px. When you set `width:0em` on `span.undo` the negative margin still plays the role. But now `legend`'s width is 2px short to render the title text on the same line so it wraps.

We can simulate the behavior. See the code comments.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* legend is behaving like a block element with width fit-content */
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: fit-content;
}

/* undo icon is inline-block */
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* title text */
span:first-child {
  color: green;
}

/* undo elements with negative margins */
.negative-margin1 {
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.negative-margin2 {
  margin-right: -40px;
}

.negative-margin3 {
  margin-right: -49px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"><span>Foo efg </span> <span>undo</span></div>
<div class="two"><span>Foo efg </span> <span class="negative-margin1">undo</span></div>
<div class="two"><span>Foo efg </span> <span class="negative-margin2">undo</span></div>
<div class="two"><span>Foo efg </span> <span class="negative-margin3">undo</span></div>
```

As the negative margin reduces width, the inline text starts wrapping.
Depending on your font size the output may slightly vary, so here is how it's intended to look:

[image]

---

We can avoid negative margin by doing a little adjustment in padding:

```css
form {
  max-width: 500px;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
}

fieldset>legend {
  font-size: 90%;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  
  /* set padding right to zero */
  padding-right: 0;
}

/* but we want 2px margin right for the title text */
span.ttl {
  margin-right: 2px;
}

span.undo {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  display: inline-block;
  height: 13px;
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  
  /*margin-right: -2px;  we don't need this now*/ 
}

legend>span.undo {
  width: 0em;
}

fieldset.modified>legend>span.undo {
  width: 1em;
}

div.description {
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset class="field">
    <legend title=""><span class='ttl'>Foo configurator</span><span class="undo" title="Restore default"></span></legend>
    <label title="">
    <input name="foo_type" type="radio" value="123">Foo #1</label>
    <div class="description">First foo</div>
    <span class="field-content">
      <label><input name="foo_enable" type="checkbox" value="value">Enable</label>
      <span class="undo" title="Restore default"></span>
    <div class="description">Zoppity</div>
    </span>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field modified">
    <legend title=""><span class='ttl'>Bar configurator</span><span class="undo" title="Restore default"></span></legend>
    <label title="">
    <input name="bar_type" type="radio" value="123">Bar #1</label>
    <div class="description">First bar</div>
    <span class="field-content">
      <label><input name="bar_enable" type="checkbox" value="value">Enable</label>
      <span class="undo" title="Restore default"></span>
    <div class="description">Zoppity</div>
    </span>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

So instead of setting negative margin on child we can have 0 padding on the parent element.

---

In the current version(100.0.4896.88), Chrome assigns following CSS, by default, to legend elements:

```css
legend {
  display: block;
  padding-inline-start: 2px;
  padding-inline-end: 2px;
  border-width: initial;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}
```

We need to check if it was different before in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

As of what is the reason for the change of behavior, I cannot tell.

Meanwhile, you can fix this behavior by adding

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

To your legend element, or

```
legend > span.undo { display: none; }
fieldset.modified > legend > span.undo { display: inline-block; }
```

Seems to do the job too, as well as to remove the negative margin

```
span.undo { margin-right: 0; }
```

Comment: yay, that fixes it! Can you help me understand why it wraps? Presumably there is white space somewhere but I don't understand why it does.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather do the `display:none;` approach. This is a UI mockup that is shared by JavaFX's sucky WebView component, and IIRC there was some problem on WebView if I did that.

Comment: The negative margin also seems to work, maybe have a look at it